# jQuery work remove id but not an element

Tags: jquery, css, attr

I have a bunch of spans, I can click on each of it and this element will be with id="active" for example. But how to remove id="active" from previous element?

```
$('#active').attr("id",'');  
$(this).attr("id","active");
```

I use this, is this valid?
After this code, elements that was an active element but now isn't active has id but it's look like

```
<span class="bunch_of_spans" id> // not active anymore (but can be active if i pick it)
<span class="bunch_of_spans" id="active"> // active now
<span class="bunch_of_spans"> // never was active
```

Is this valid and may be there is method to remove id from elements that doesn't active? Thanks

Comment: I just use a class and do `$('.active').removeClass('active');`.

Comment: Better way is to add and remove class as said by Blender. Use `$('#some_id').addClass('active');` to add class and `$('#some_id').removeClass('active');` to remove class.

Comment: Note, empty `id` attributes are invalid. I'd use @Blender's method and use a class.

Comment: Thanks, i don't think about class, think it will be nice solution. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your specific question, use:

```
$('#active').removeAttr("id");
```

But semantically, the id's should never change, so I recommend you to use classes instead, like:

```
<span class="bunch_of_spans active">
```

and you add/remove the class like this:

```
$('#active').addClass("active");
$('#active').removeClass("active");
```

Answer (score 4):

use [removeAttr](http://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/)

```
$('#active').removeAttr("id");
```

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/nWtYc/

Although this will work I suggest you to use some other non-unique identifier to identify active elements. classes work good for this.